# How to include field value in Oracle Apex Pre Element Text

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using Apex 19.1  I have a display-only item (P211_TIME) on an apex page.  I'd like to reference the value of another page item (P211_SELECT_LIT) in the item's Advanced / Pre Text.  How do I reference P211_SELECT_LIT?  I've tried &P211_SELECT_LIT and #P211_SELECT_LIT#.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close - references within (what will be) HTML need the following syntax.

```
&P211_SELECT_LIT.
```

Note the trailing full-stop - that's part of the required syntax.

I highly recommend reading through the [substutition strings](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/understanding-substitution-strings.html#GUID-A896A94B-DF69-4D53-B422-3256C09AE464) section of the documentation.
I've ready these particular pages many times, and still do.

Comment: That fixed it Scott.  A Period after the field name.  Thanks very much!  Phil